# Import and Export Question on Older Versions

Tags: modeling, error

Recently, I imported a knife into Blender 2.76.

[image]

Afterwards, I exported the knife as an Obj. I desire to convert it to a nif., so I imported it into Blender 2.49b, but it came out like this:
[image]

What went wrong? I am relatively new to this. So it may be something I missed.

Comment: It appears that 2.49 is importing the bounding box. Why 2.49 though? Is it necessary to use that version for some script?

Comment: Yes, I need it in order to covert the file to nif. Apparently, it works best for that version. Am I able to get rid of the bounding box? I noticed I can in 2.79.

Comment: Maybe there's some other object hidden in the viewport but being exported since it looks like there's tiny sharp piece of the knife looking through on the left of that box. Try to enable Only Selected when exporting or remove all objects from the scene in 2.79 but knife object and export.